# Unable to run javascript from vscode

Tags: javascript, html, dom, visual-studio-code, web-applications

I am a beginner in JS.
on my html I have piece of code like this:

```html
<script src="index.js"></script>
```

and in my javascript I have:

```js
var javascriptGreeting = ' hello world'
console.log(javascriptGreeting)
```

But when I run my html code, I do not have an output from the console, although I have vscode javascript extension installed....

Comment: "when I run my html code" — How, exactly, are you doing that?

Comment: @Quentin in my vscode, I´ve got a file called `index.html` and when I use liveserver the index.html is displayed in the browser...

Comment: And which console are you looking in? The browser's or VS Code's?

Comment: Show your full html code @user221459

Comment: @Quentin yes, I am not sure where the output should pop up, but not having anything in the browser ou vscode

Comment: I copy/pasted the code and ran it with VS Code Live Server. It worked fine.

Comment: @Quentin where the output was logged? in the vscode or browser?

Comment: The browser. It is client-side code.

Comment: @Quentin I cannot see anything....

Answer (score -1):

Where did you put the script file source?
Try this: Put that `<script src="index.js"></script>` at the end of the body content.

Comment: The script doesn't access the DOM. That won't make any difference.

Comment: @RayeesAC below is the bottom of my html code: `    <script src="index.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>`  then the code of my index.js file: `var javascriptGreeting = ' hello world'
console.log(javascriptGreeting)`

Comment: @Theo, did not change anything

Comment: I saw in in the web, that I shoud use `node -v index.js`  in command prompt, but that did not work either

Answer (score -2):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="index.js"></script>
```

i think this should help.

you must specify the programming language in the script tag

Comment: No. See [the spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/scripting.html#attr-script-type): Omitting the attribute, setting it to the empty string, or setting it to a JavaScript MIME type essence match, means that the script is a classic script, to be interpreted according to the JavaScript Script top-level production. Classic scripts are affected by the async and defer attributes, but only when the src attribute is set. **Authors should omit the type attribute instead of redundantly setting it**